# How to obtain the continuity of a binary function w.r.t. one of it's variables, in Applebaum's book for Levy processes?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-analysis, levy-processes

My question came from [page 392 of of D. Applebaum's book "Levy processes and Stochastic calculus"](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=q7eDUjdJxIkC&pg=PA328&dq=Levy+processes+and+Stochastic+calculus+note+that+if+assumption+6.5.1&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXoc2E6J3QAhUJTrwKHWWOArMQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I will put it in a nutshell.

> Let $\nu$ be a measure on $B_c(0)\setminus\{0\}$ satisfying $\int_{0<|x|<c}|x|^2\,\nu(dx)<\infty$. Function $F:\mathbb R^d\times(B_c(0)-\{0\})\to\mathbb R$ satisfies
>   \begin{equation}\tag 1
> \int_{0<|x|<c}|F(y_1,x)-F(y_2,x)|^2\,\nu(dx)<K|y_1-y_2|^2,\quad \forall y_1,y_2\in\mathbb R^d,
> \end{equation}
>   and 
>   \begin{equation}\tag 2
> |F(y,x)|\le|\rho(x)||\delta(y)|,\quad \forall y\in\mathbb R^d，x\in B_c(0)\setminus\{0\},
> \end{equation}
>   where $\rho:B_c(0)\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $\int_{0<|x|<c}|\rho(x)|^2\,\nu(dx)<\infty$ and $\delta:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ is Lipschitz continuous.
>
> **Question:** Prove that for each $x\in B_c(0)\setminus\{0\}$, the mapping $y\to F(y,x)$ is continuous.

What I can conclude is from $(1)$ that
$$
F(y_n,x)\to F(y,x) \text{ in } L^2(B_c(0)\setminus\{0\},\nu), \quad \text{as } y_n\to y,
$$
as a consequence, there is a subsequence $\{y_{n_k}\}$ such that $
F(y_{n_k},x)\to F(y,x)$ for $\nu$-a.s. $x$. But how to get the continuity of $F(\cdot,x)$ for each $x$?

Any comments will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the given assumptions, continuity of $F(\cdot,x)$ for $\nu$-almost all $x$ is the best what we can expect.

Suppose, for instance, that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. Define

$$F(y,x) := \begin{cases} yx, & x \neq \frac{c}{2}, \\ x 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(y) & x = \frac{c}{2} \end{cases}.$$

Obviously, $y \mapsto F(y,c/2)$ is not continuous. On the other hand, we have

$$|F(y,x)| \leq |\varrho(x)| \, |\delta(y)|$$

for $\varrho(x) := x$ and $\varrho(y) := \max\{|y|,1\}$. Moreover

$$\begin{align*} \int_{0<|x|<c} |F(y_1,x)-F(y_2,x)|^2 \, \nu(dx) &= \int_{0<|x|<c, x \neq \frac{c}{2}} |F(y_1,x)-F(y_2,x)|^2 \, \nu(dx) \\ &= |y_1-y_2|^2 \int_{0<|x|<c} x^2 \, \nu(dx) \\ &=: K |y_1-y_2|^2 \end{align*}$$ which means that $F$ satisfies all the given assumptions.

Comment: It's an excellent counterexample! While, I feel that there is even some obstacle to obtain the continuity of $F(\cdot,x)$ for $\nu$-a.a. $x$. What we know is that, for any sequence $\{y_n\}$, there is a subsequence $\{y_{n_k}\}$ and a set $\Omega_{y_n}$ with $\nu(\Omega_{y_n})=1$, such that $F(y_{n_k},x)\to F(y,x)$ for $\forall x\in\Omega_{y_n}$. But the full measure set $\Omega_{y_n}$ depends on the sequence $\{y_n\}$, while the continuity of $F(\cdot,x)$ for $\nu$-a.a. $x$ is to find a uniformly full measure set $\Omega$.

Comment: @Q.Huang Yes, you are right... do you know what kind of continuity Applebaum uses in the proof?

Comment: Thanks. Actually Applebaum do not use the continuity argument hereafter, but later he made another similar argument in [page 396](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=gbe8L1i6trYC&pg=PA396&dq=Levy+processes+and+Stochastic+calculus+assumption+6.6.1&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK9LaEpKjQAhVNO7wKHaXRAW0Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @Q.Huang Does he? There is no mention of pointwise continuity... or have I overlooked it?

Comment: Ok. It is not a mention of continuity but a mention which made some similar kind of mistake. In the middle row of page 396, he mentioned that if Assumption 6.5.1 holds then Assumption 6.6.1 (i) and (ii) is simply the requirement that $\int_{|x|<c}|\rho(x)|^p\,\nu(dx)<\infty$ for all $p\in[2,\gamma\lor\gamma']$. I think that this mention is also wrong.